# how to delete the row and its child in entity framework 4

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a simple and beginner question.

I have two tables with 1 to N relationship. I want to when I delete a row in parent table, in an

other table the child of that row delete too.

How can I do that using entity framework?

Comment: you can add cascade delete in database

Answer (score 0):

Probably it was asked before, refer to the link below:

[Delete an object and all of its related entities in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937140/)

I do believe that you should handle that at Database level by using `CASCADE DELETE ON`.

Comment: I do that but there is a error : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
my code is :

 <End Role="Table_infobase_print" Type="doctorModel.Table_infobase_print" Multiplicity="1">
            <OnDelete Action="Cascade"></OnDelete>
          </End>
          <End Role="Table_infodetail_print" Type="doctorModel.Table_infodetail_print" Multiplicity="*" />

Comment: could you please provide more detail as I won't be able to solve with this much info