# How to delete all many-to-many relations without loading related entities in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have db scheme where Product table have many to many relation to Color table. I'm using EF and create POCO objects:

```
public class Product
{ 
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Color> Colors {get;set;}
}

public class Color
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

In many situations it is necessary to delete all colors related to product and set new colors. So i want to delete all many to many relations whitout exactly knowing id of related colors. Is it possible to delete them without additional queries to db? I know i can just write stored procedure which will delete all relation with colors for specified product, but it will be better to find general approach through entity framework.

Comment: just follow this link : 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937140/delete-an-object-and-all-of-its-related-entities-in-entity-framework][1]


cheers!

Comment: I don't want to delete product or colors itself, i just want to delete all relations between specific product and all the colors. So i can't use cascade delete because there is no delete of related entities, only delete of relation.

Comment: you can store your entity(product or color) in a temporary variable and after deleting , insert it with different id.i think you cant find a way more efficient than this.

Comment: In my question there is only simple example. In real model i have many relations on products and on colors too. So if i delete color or product i delete all relations. So i must store all product relations, then delete product, then insert product with all relations without color relation. It is very inefficient and in this case i must load all other product relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know keys of colors you cannot delete them without loading them first - EF deletes records one by one so it needs to know which record to delete.

The straight forward option is executing SQL `DELETE` directly:

```
dbContext.Database
         .ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.ProductColors WHERE ProductId = @Id", product.Id);
```