# How to delete entity with all its related entities in a code-first approach

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete an object and all of its related entities in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937140/delete-an-object-and-all-of-its-related-entities-in-entity-framework)

I have looked for a while on how to do this, but found none of the posts addressing this issue.
These are the classes for setting up the db:

```
public class Claim
{
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DraftID { get; set; } 
    public int ClaimID { get; set; } 
    public string SupplierCode { get; set; }
    public ClaimStatus Status { get; set; }
    public Policy Policy { get; set; }
}
```

my context:

```
public class FnxDbContext:DbContext {
 public FnxDbContext() : base() { this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; } public DbSet<Claim> Claim { get; set; }
```

Now let's say I want to remove the `Claim`-entity with the DraftID that is "1"
(there is such a record in the DB with FK to other tables as needed)
How do I do this? I tried many ideas I found on the net. Most of them talk about a single entity.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: you've got a context class (inherting from DbContext) and do override OnModelCreating ? if yes, can you show the part concerning the Claim Entity ?

Comment: my context:   public class FnxDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public FnxDbContext()
            : base()
        {
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }
        public DbSet<Claim> Claim { get; set; }

Comment: What do you want to remove? A single `Claim` plus the related `Status` plus the related `Policy`???

Comment: yes that is what i want @ do