# Entity framework unable to delete object with relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I have two tables with a 1:1 relation. I created them using the model first approach of entity framework. Now i want to delete a record, but i can't delete from one table and not the other, when i try i get the following exception:

'A relationship is being added or deleted from an AssociationSet 'FK_lm_ab_profile_lm_profile_master'. With cardinality constraints, a corresponding 'lm_ab_profile' must also be added or deleted.'

i have a profile table with a relationship to ABProfile, i want to delete from profile and AbProfile. they both use profile_id as a PK, and ABProfile has profile_id as a FK

My Code:

```
        //Get the old profile to see if one already exists
            var oldProfile = context.lm_profile_master.FirstOrDefault(p => p.profile_id.Equals(profileID));

            lm_ab_profile ab = new lm_ab_profile();

            //Check to see if user doesn't already exist
            if (oldProfile != null)
            {

                    //try and specify the relationship between profile and ABProfile using profileID
                    oldProfile.lm_ab_profileReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("luminusEntities.lm_ab_profile", "profile_id", profileID);    


                    //remove found object from the database and persist changes  

                    context.DeleteObject(oldProfile);
                    context.SaveChanges();
              }
```

How can i specify the two tables are related so when i delete a record from one, the other record get delete also...i set my tables for the Cascading function on the model.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you described is constraint between tables. You try to affect consistency.

Look at this [Delete an object and all of its related entities in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937140/delete-an-object-and-all-of-its-related-entities-in-entity-framework) and define ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: Yes i have set that up, but when i try delete a table it asks me to specify the table with the FK, in this case ABprofile reference to profile master in null...that's what i was trying to archive above.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood it correctly.
But if you set ON DELETE ACTION correctly it's impossible that ABprofile has null reference to MasterProfile. 

Maybe you set ON DELETE ACTION = SET NULL ?

I'm not a Entity Framework user, but I think it's DB layer problem.

Comment: Looks like my object state manager is not organised properly, been debugging, but can't find a thing in this maize